# Grey spots on skin (Render of a person)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I was just rendering a person and it's got these weird spots.

[image]

This is what I see in Blender:
[image]

My render settings:

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AJfC.png)
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you have a second mesh with similar geometry but coarser resolution a the same location as your person mesh?

Comment: Rather than showing us the render settings, show us the material. Also the denoiser can cause similar artefacts.